# redux react strategy with async data and interaction

Tags: reactjs, redux

I am wondering what design would be best for this. I have a list that is fetched remotely. Let's say it's a list of posts.

```
posts  {
    1: { title: 'some title', body: 'some body'},
    2: { title: 'another title', body: 'another body'}
}
```

In this list a user can select each post for an action (and even batch actions). Let's say that in the UI each small post will have a checkbox.

So, the backend doesn't care about these select actions, but I need to know exactly which posts are selected (for deletion for example) so that the front end can send a request to the backend. One way to handle that is to have the shape of the state look like this:

```
{
    posts  {
        1: { title: 'some title', body: 'some body'},
        2: { title: 'another title', body: 'another body'}
    }
    selectedPosts: [1, 2]
}
```

But that might make rendering complicated in the UI.

Then the alternative is to directly modify the data for each post when the post is selected. Like this:

```
{
    posts  {
        1: { title: 'some title', body: 'some body', selected: true},
        2: { title: 'another title', body: 'another body'}
    }
}
```

But this seems antithetical to how react & redux are intended to be used. Any feedback is appreciated!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'd go with the former approach, and write any sort of helpers you need to massage the data into what you need. For example, a simple `map` could get all the selected posts:

```javascript
const selectedPosts = state.selectedPosts.map(id => state.posts[id]);
```

You'd use something like this in your `connect` function, or use something like [reselect](https://github.com/faassen/reselect):

```javascript
import { createSelector } from 'reselect';

const postsSelector = state => state.posts;
const selectedPostIdsSelector = state => state.selectedPosts;

const selectedPostsSelector = createSelector(
  postsSelector ,
  selectedPostIdsSelector ,
  (posts, selectedPosts) => selectedPosts.map(id => posts[id]);
);
```

Comment: Good answer, but the reselect api is hard to digest.

Comment: Thanks for the confirmation!

Comment: @RickJolly You don't have to use Reselect API to write functions that take the state and return a state-ready-for-UI-components. See [Redux example in Flux Comparison](https://github.com/voronianski/flux-comparison/tree/master/redux) for selectors that don't even use Reselect.